# Show that there exist $\gamma\in[\alpha,\beta] $ such that $\int\limits_{E}f|g|=\gamma\int\limits_{E}|g|$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, mean-value-theorem

> Suppose $f:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable, $g:E\rightarrow R$
>   is Lebesgue integrable and there exists $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
>   $\alpha\leq f(x)\leq\beta$ for almost every $x\in E$. Show that there
>   exist $\gamma\in[\alpha,\beta] $ such that $\int\limits_{E}
>  f|g|=\gamma\int\limits_{E}|g|$

For this I can multiply the inequality by $|g|$ and get
$\alpha|g|\leq f|g|\leq\beta|g|$

Now **IF** I could apply the integration throughout the inequality then
$\int\limits_E\alpha|g|\leq \int\limits_Ef|g|\leq\int\limits_E\beta|g|$

So by taking $\gamma=\frac{\int\limits_Ef|g|}{\int\limits_E|g|}$ we can get the answer.

But my doubt is whether it is possible to apply the integration mark along the inequality. Because the monotonicity of the Lebesgue integral was defined for non negative functions (although it was not integrable.) And I don't see a method to say that the function $f|g|$ is integrable.

In my reference (that is *Real analysis by Fitzpatrick*) Lebesgue integrability for a measurable function were defined to be the case when: 
$$\int\limits_E|f|<\infty$$

Comment: you can apply the integral to the inequality, the integral is a positive operator, that is $f\le g\implies\int f\le\int g$, and $f|g|$ is clearly integrable because $f$ is bounded and $|g|$ is integrable

Comment: "And for the ...." ?

Comment: @Masacroso How do we say that $f$ is bounded?

Comment: @Jack sorry it was a mistake. I deleted that

Comment: You need to look at $f|g|$ not $f$ on its own.

Comment: @gune because $-\infty <\alpha \leqslant f(x)\leqslant \beta <\infty $ in $E$. Maybe I would say that $f$ is _essentially bounded_, that is, we dont care what is $f$ in a set of measure zero

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for the clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to clarify that if $\displaystyle\int|g|=0$, then $g=0$ a.e. and $\gamma\in[\alpha,\beta]$ can be taken as arbitrary.

If it were not, then $\gamma=\dfrac{\displaystyle\int f|g|}{\displaystyle\int|g|}$ would be a candidate. And we know that $(\cdot)\geq(\cdot\cdot)$ implies that $\displaystyle\int(\cdot)\geq\int(\cdot\cdot)$ no matter $(\cdot),(\cdot\cdot)$ are positive or negative or not.